# How can I get rid of the sub module for recipes so I can have access to my recipe links and get rid of the repos directory on the repository

Tags: html, github, git-submodules

[Submodules on repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeDoA.png)

I've tried deleting the repos in Github but it proceeds to stay. No idea on how to get access to recipes.

Comment: Either… 1: Delete the folder on the source and `git push` (be aware that the folder will still be visible in the history). 2: Add the folder to your `.gitignore` and `git push` (same as last time, it’s visible in the history). To remove it from the history, you can delete the repo on GitHub **AND** your local machine (delete the `.git` repo), recreate the repo on both platforms (`git init`), and recommit and push (`git add -A && git commit -am “Initial commit”`, add remote, `git push`).